# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Мой код таков

```
create or replace trigger "TBL_REGISTRY_T1"
AFTER INSERT
    ON "TBL_REGISTRY"
for each row
BEGIN
:NEW.CLM_CONCATANTE := 'в размере ' || ROUND(:NEW.CLM_CONTRACT_ENDING_AMOUNT,2) || ' (' || NUMBER2WORD_RU(:NEW.CLM_CONTRACT_ENDING_AMOUNT)  || ') сум '|| ' страхователю ' ||
 CASE  :NEW.CLM_RETURNUSER
    when 'бошқага' then  'согласно заявлению страхователя ' || :NEW.CLM_GETOTHER 
    else :NEW.CLM_GETOWNER 
 end 
 || ' путем перечисления по следующему банковскому реквизиту: р/с: ' || :NEW.CLM_RETURN_RS || ' МФО: 00' || :NEW.CLM_RETURN_MFO ||
 CASE  :NEW.CLM_CLIENT_TYPE
    when 'жисмоний' then  ' п/к: ' || :NEW.CLM_RETURN_CARDNUM 
    else NULL 
 end 
 || ' согласно расчету возврата страховой премии от ' ||  :NEW.CLM_ORDER_DATE || ' года'
```

при компиляции пишет :

*Compilation failed, line 12 (19:02:02) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || member submultiset*

Comment: else NULL  - а конкатенировать NULL можно?

Comment: Извините меня, я новичок в этом мире, если не правильно я написал, как тут исправить ?